# why annotation: rewrite-target are required in ingress service

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I created an ingress service from the kubernetes documentation, but I found that not putting below annotation made service unavailable. Why was this so?

```
annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
```

Main reason to ask this question was that in K8s documentation, I found below code for ingress, but this did not work until and unless I put the above annotation. So, why does the below code not work?

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-wear-watch
  namespace: app-space
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /wear
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: wear-service
            port:
              number: 8080
      - path: /watch
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: video-service
            port:
              number: 8080
```

Comment: That depends on the applications being served behind the ingress. If your app, for example, expect requests to come under the domain / then it makes sense that it doesn't work without the rewrite target, if it is being served under a subpath.

Comment: @user10953785 I did not discourage anyone, it was a genuine question whether you checked the documentation yet or not. You would be surprised how many people ask a question without doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [k8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/annotations/), all you need to know in this specific case is that

> you can use Kubernetes annotations to attach arbitrary non-identifying metadata to objects. Clients such as tools and libraries can retrieve this metadata.
> [annotations are] Directives from the end-user to the implementations to modify behavior or engage non-standard features.

So basically this specific annotations are used to modify behaviour of ingress and are specififc to nginx ingress controller (this means that if you use different controller, this annotations wont work).

All supported annotations for nginx ingress controler are explained in [Nginx Ingress Controller documention](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/).